# Google Map Place APIPlace API search limit exceeds yesterday(23rd,December,2015) but today again it showing limit exceeds

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am facing some critical problem to search Google Place API auto search. It all time shows that

> "error_message": "You have exceeded your daily request quota for this
>   API."

Can you please share me the solution of this issue. Thanks to you in advance.

Comment: do you use your own key to perform the requests? This error means that you have already performed a pretty high number of requests that day (somewhere around 2500). And this might be because somebody else using the same API key has done that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message you got is pretty self explanatory, **You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API**. Wait for the next day, or buy a plan. [Here are the prices](https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/?hl=es)

Answer (score 0):

Check if 24 hours have elapsed since the time you exceeded you daily limit. Or may be the guys at google are at Christmas Holiday ;)